# How to package a pom project as runnable jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a free project that is all based on Free and Open source programs:

- some of them have pom and public accessible jars
- some of them have pom but no public accessible jars
- some of them have no pom

I want to distribute the project as a unique jar since all licences are compatible I legally can, if it's possible to generate such a jar with maven, I don't know how. Can you help?

If it's not possible what is the best way to distribute such project?

---

My pom is managed by netbeans, here is the missing configuration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- I added the following -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>net.hypermove.graphitidb.GraphitiDB</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: The above link was likely found with a Google for "maven executable jar" - it is the first hit in my case. Something to remember for the next time you have a "how do I do this" type of tool question: Google is your friend!

Answer (score 6):

There are many options for you

1. [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) with [jar-with-dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies) descriptor
2. [Maven One Jar](https://code.google.com/p/onejar-maven-plugin/) Plugin
3. Distribution Jar - Zip Archive with your jar, all dependencies in directory lib and configured manifest for easy execution. Sample configuration below.
4. [Executable Jar](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) with [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)
5. Runnable Jar with dependencies mapped to local maven repository (possible, but not portable) [Altering The Classpath: Using a Maven Repository-Style Classpath](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#aRepository)

## 1. Jar Assembled With Dependencies

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-jar-with-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>eu.codearte.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

## 2. Maven One Jar

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>eu.codearte.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
    <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>one-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com</id>
        <url>http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

## 3. Distribution Jar configuration

### Maven Dependency Plugin

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                <stripVersion>false</stripVersion>
                <stripClassifier>false</stripClassifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

### Maven Assembly Plugin

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/bundle.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

### Maven Jar Plugin

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
       <execution>
            <id>exe-jar</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <classifier>exe</classifier>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>eu.codearte.MainClass</mainClass>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <useUniqueVersions>false</useUniqueVersions>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

### Assembly Descriptor

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<assembly
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>bundle</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>target/lib</directory>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>target/project-exe.jar</source>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </file>
    </files>
</assembly>
```

Comment: After using the shade plugin for years, I've been very happy with the assembly plugin, which builds much faster, and is easier to verify in a production environment since all dependencies are viewable in the package instead of being aggregated into one huge jar.